# Simple norm equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Please I need help with this problem.

---

Let $V$ be the vector space consisting of functions which are continuous over the interval $[0,1]$, take the value $0$ at the points $0$ and $1$ and are once piecewise continuously differentiable over the same interval. When equipped with the mapping
$$v\in V\rightarrow\|v\|_V\ :=\ \left(\int_0^1(|v^{\prime}|^2 + |v|^2)dx\right)^{1/2},$$
the vector space is normed.

Prove that there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$\sup_{0\leq x\leq 1}|v(x)|\ \leq\ C\|v\|_V \quad\mbox{ for every } v\in V.$$

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you stuck? We can give you more help if we know where you need it.

Comment: Well, first at all, I really don't know how I can start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v(x)$ be in the space. Suppose $\max |v(x)|=|v(x_0)|$, i.e. $|v(x)|$ attains its maximum at $x=x_0$. Then
$$\max |v(x)|=|v(x_0)|=\left|\int_0^{x_0} v'(t)\,dt\right|$$
Now use Holder inequality to get
$$\left|\int_0^{x_0} v'(t)\,dt\right|\le \left(\int_0^1v'(t)^2\,dt\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^1 1\,dt\right)^{1/2}\le \|v\|_V$$
So in fact you have
$$\sup_{0\leq x\leq 1}|v(x)|\ \leq\ \|v\|_V \quad\mbox{ for every } v\in V.$$
In the second last inequality, you use $$\int_0^{x_0}v'(t)^2\,dt\le \int_0^{1}v'(t)^2\,dt$$ and similar for the integral of 1.